# Problem to send send push notifications to iOS, (cloud function)

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently very stuck in push notification for iOS, (Works for Android but not on iOS)

I set up everything correctly and I know how to send push notifications through the cloud messaging console.

I use google firebase functions for that:

Does anyone know how I can fix this on iOS, I am very stuck, its works with android.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { firestore, messaging } = require("./admin");
const PromiseAllSettled = require("promise.allsettled");

/**
 *
 * Sends only to doctor when appointment doc is
 * created.
 *
 * Push notification to every device token
 * the doctor has.
 *
 */
const pushOnCreate = functions.firestore
  .document("appointments/{id}")
  .onCreate(async (snap) => {
    const data = snap.data();
    const doctorId = data.doctorId;

    var tokenDocument = await firestore
      .collection("doctors")
      .doc(doctorId)
      .collection("tokens")
      .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) {
          let pushTokenList = [];
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            pushTokenList.push(doc.data().pushToken);
          });
          return { success: true, payload: pushTokenList };
        } else {
          return { noData: true };
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error while getting token documents", error);
        return { error: error.toString() };
      });

    if (tokenDocument.success !== undefined) {
      // Create a list of promises
      let tokenList = tokenDocument.payload;
      let promiseList = [];

      tokenList.forEach((token) => {
        console.log(`Create notification token for: `, token);
        const payload = {
          token: token,
          notification: {
            title: "Nouveau rendez-vous",
            body: "Vous avez un nouveau rendez-vous pour " + data.title,
          },
          android: {
            priority: "high",
            notification: {
              title: "Nouveau rendez-vous",
              body: "Vous avez un nouveau rendez-vous pour " + data.title,
              priority: "max",
              clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
              channelId: "appointment_channel",
              defaultSound: true,
              defaultVibrateTimings: true,
              defaultLightSettings: true,
              visibility: "public",
              ticker: "Nouveau rendez-vous",
            },
          },
          apns: {
            headers: {
              "apns-priority": "10",
            },
            payload: {
              aps: {
                alert: {
                  title: "Nouveau rendez-vous",
                  body: "Vous avez un nouveau rendez-vous pour " + data.title,
                },
                sound: {
                  critical: true,
                  name: "default",
                  volume: 1.0,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        };

        // Add new promise to the list of promises.
        const newPromise = messaging.send(payload);
        promiseList.push(newPromise);
      });

      return await PromiseAllSettled(promiseList)
        .then((_) => {
          console.log(`Notification Sent`);
          return true;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.error(`Notification operation failed.`, { details: e });
          return false;
        });
    } else {
      console.log("Either no data or an error");
      return Promise.resolve("Either no data or an error");
    }
  });

/**
 *
 * Sends notification to user when the doctor is online
 * and ready for the appointment.
 *
 */
const pushOnUpdate = functions.firestore
  .document("appointments/{id}")
  .onUpdate(async (change) => {
    const beforeData = change.before.data();
    const data = change.after.data();
    const userId = data.userId;
    const isDoctorActive = data.isDoctorActive;
    const isUserActive = data.isUserActive;

    if (isUserActive) {
      console.log("User is already active");
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    // If the doctor is active and user is not active only then send the notification to the user.
    if (isDoctorActive && !beforeData.isUserActive) {
      var tokenDocument = await firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(userId)
        .collection("tokens")
        .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.empty) {
            console.log("No matching documents.");
            return { noData: true };
          } else {
            let pushTokenList = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              pushTokenList.push(doc.data().pushToken);
            });
            return { success: true, payload: pushTokenList };
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error while getting token documents", error);
          return { error: "Error" };
        });

      // After getting the document send the notification message.
      if (tokenDocument.success !== undefined) {
        // Create a list of promises
        let tokenList = tokenDocument.payload;
        let promiseList = [];

        // Loop through it and create a promise list
        tokenList.forEach((token) => {
          console.info("Create notification for token ", token);
          // Create the notification object.
          const payload = {
            token: token,
            notification: {
              title: "Votre psychologue est en ligne",
              body:
                "Ç'est l'heure de votre séance de " +
                data.title +
                ". Accédez y vite.",
            },
            data: {
              appointmentDocument: JSON.stringify(data),
            },
            android: {
              priority: "high",
              notification: {
                title: "Votre psychologue est en ligne",
                body:
                  "Ç'est l'heure de votre séance de " +
                  data.title +
                  ". Accédez y vite.",
                priority: "max",
                clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                channelId: "appointment_channel",
                defaultSound: true,
                defaultVibrateTimings: true,
                defaultLightSettings: true,
                visibility: "public",
                ticker: "Nouveau rendez-vous",
              },
            },
            apns: {
              headers: {
                "apns-priority": "10",
              },
              payload: {
                aps: {
                  alert: {
                    title: "Votre psychologue est en ligne",
                    body:
                      "Ç'est l'heure de votre séance de " +
                      data.title +
                      ". Accédez y vite.",
                  },
                  sound: {
                    critical: true,
                    name: "default",
                    volume: 1.0,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          };
          // Add new promise to the list of promises.
          const newPromise = messaging.send(payload);
          promiseList.push(newPromise);
        });

        return await PromiseAllSettled(promiseList)
          .then((_) => {
            console.log(`Notification Sent`);
            return true;
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.error(`Notification operation failed.`, { details: e });
            return false;
          });
      } else {
        console.log("No token document found as there was an error");
        return Promise.resolve("No token document found as there was an error");
      }
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Doctor is not active or the user was just active and is not active now."
      );
      return Promise.resolve();
    }
  });

module.exports = {
  pushOnCreate,
  pushOnUpdate,
};
```

Comment: Did you use real device or just simulator?

Comment: real device (iPhone 8)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to register your application with APNS, in order to receive notifications:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns

Comment: i do that bro already. thanks for your help

Comment: What's the error code of the [`ApnsError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW15)?

Comment: Can you help me modify the code (if you can)

Comment: i don't have any apns errors

Comment: "it's not working" is not an error description... and I see little motivation to fix your code, especially when you yourself are too lazy to look up the returned error-code, which would make it a proper question... it's likely that the payload is wrong; eg. sound files on iOS usually end with `*.aiff`.

Comment: 2021-10-16 17:58:01.105955+0100 Runner[6445:291606] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C15.1 142.*50.*00.238:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed

Comment: the problem was when I sent a test message from 'Cloud Messaging' (firebase panel) I receive a notification on my iphone.